# How terminate RG8 coaxial cable using PL259 (UHF) - screw - gasket - solder type?

Tags: coaxial-cable, connectors, pl259-so239-connector

Today I came across a problem in terminating RG8 cable using this PL259 plug.

I have never had this type and it arrived in a pile of parts; I have tried to puzzle it together but without positive effect. While googling i came only across crimping and screw-in; I also checked YT but no luck with this type.

Could someone who work with this type connector tell me how this should looks like and what order parts should go together in?

For reference I gave them numbers (random numbers, I don't know which comes first etc).

[image]

Comment: There are instructions online (and in the ARRL Handbook) so I trust this will generate a useful reference answer.

Comment: Is there a number stamped on the large part? If so, try Googling it. I have assembled N connectors like this, but not of this type.

Comment: This looks like an [Altelix connector](https://www.altelix.com/UHF-Male-PL-259-Clamp-Connector-400-Series-p/cc400wum.htm). Unfortunately they seem to not provide any instructions or even a drawing. Closest I can find with instructions is one from [Pomona](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/159/d73059_001-54085.pdf).

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Your Pomona link looks good enough for an answer! What they call a ferrule should be the red gasket in the OP.

Comment: I confirm, i look from all sides and this is Altelix connector (or it's clone). Thank You for data-sheet for Pomona but on mine i have different size of washers so i'm still unsure .
I would like learn to make it properly without guessing (it will be outside).

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Phil's comment, there is a decent cutaway view:

[Pomona Model 73059 UHF Plug, Clamp Type, RG 8](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/159/d73059_001-54085.pdf) (mouser.com)

Excerpt:

[image]

Comment: The OP's photo showed two different washers. In this photo, which washer is which? Its JPEG compression artifacts make the washers fuzzy when zoomed (should have been saved as a GIF or PNG!) and the text there doesn't tell is that. Plus, The OP's is not a crimped center conductor, it's soldered.